# Query all columns where column contains specific word not working?

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter

I'm trying to set up a database for a quiz. I wanna store [quizName] in one column, and [quizQuestions] in the second column.

The problem is that even if the database is created and column exists, I get the error "no such column: *COLUMN-NAME*"

At the same time, if I query ALL data in the table, I actually get all the values from each column. I can't really find the bug, what am I doing wrong?

```
    class DatabaseHelper {
      static final _databaseName = "MyDatabase.db";
      static final _databaseVersion = 7;

      static final table = 'my_table';
      static final quizID = 'quizID';
      static final quizQuestions = 'quizQuestions';

      // make this a singleton class
      DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
      static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

      // only have a single app-wide reference to the database
      static Database _database;
      Future<Database> get database async {
        if (_database != null) return _database;
        // lazily instantiate the db the first time it is accessed
        _database = await _initDatabase();
        return _database;
      }

      // this opens the database (and creates it if it doesn't exist)
      _initDatabase() async {
        Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, _databaseName);
        return await openDatabase(path,
            version: _databaseVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
      }

      // SQL code to create the database table
      Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
        await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $table ($quizID TEXT, $quizQuestions TEXT)');
      }

      // Helper methods

      // Inserts a row in the database where each key in the Map is a column name
      // and the value is the column value. The return value is the id of the
      // inserted row.
      Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
        Database db = await instance.database;
        return await db.insert(table, row);
      }

      // All of the rows are returned as a list of maps, where each map is
      // a key-value list of columns.
      Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAllRows() async {
        Database db = await instance.database;
        return await db.query(table);
      }

      // All of the methods (insert, query, update, delete) can also be done using
      // raw SQL commands. This method uses a raw query to give the row count.
      Future<int> queryRowCount() async {
        Database db = await instance.database;
        return Sqflite.firstIntValue(
            await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table'));
      }

// Below method is not finding column
      Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryQuestions(String quizName) async {
        Database db = await instance.database;
        return await db
            .rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $quizID = $quizName');
      }

      // We are assuming here that the id column in the map is set. The other
      // column values will be used to update the row.
      Future<int> update(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
        Database db = await instance.database;
        int id = row[quizID];
        return await db.update(table, row, where: '$quizID = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
      }

      // Deletes the row specified by the id. The number of affected rows is
      // returned. This should be 1 as long as the row exists.
      Future<int> delete(int id) async {
        Database db = await instance.database;
        return await db.delete(table, where: '$quizID = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
      }
    }
```

Best Regards,
Rusben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
return await db
            .rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $quizID = $quizName');
```

to this instead

```
return await db
            .rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $quizID = ?', [quizName]);
```

You are basically missing quotes before and after $quizName, but it is better to use ? parameters anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. So now I query full row, how about I wanna query all columns only where certain condition is fulfilled? Rather than return full row. // Rusben